# glmulti Oversized candidate set

Tags: memory-management, feature-selection

Error message:

> SYSTEM: win7/64bit/ultimate/16gb-real-ram plus virtual memory,
>   memory.limit(32000)

1. What does this error message mean?

   In glmulti(y = "y", data = mydf, xr = c("x1",  :  !Oversized candidate set.

   mydf has 3.6mm rows & 150 columns of floats
2. What steps to take to workaround it in glmulti?
3. Any alternatives to glmulti in R world?

R/64bit "Good Sport"

Comment: Any update in this one?

Answer (score 6):

I have encountered the same problem, here is what I have found out so far:

1. The number of rows does not seem to be the issue. The issue is that with 150 predictors the package can't handle an exhaustive search (that is take a look and compare all possible models). From my experience your specific error message "Oversized Candidate Set", is triggered by the fact that you also allow for pairwise interactions (`level=2`, set `level=1` to prohibit interactions). Then you will most likely run into a warning message "Too many predictors". In my (very limited) experimentation, I found that the maximum amount of models I got to work into the candidate set was about a billion models (specifically: 30 covariates equal 1,073,741,824 based on the 2^n to calculate possible combinations (n=30).). Here is the code I used to evaluate this

   `out <integer(50)
   for(i in 2:40) 
   out[i]<-glmulti(names(data)[1], names(data)[2:i], method="d", level=1, crit=aic, data=data)`

   once the loop hits 31 covariates the candidate set returns with 0 models. 33 and later it starts returning the warning message. My "data" had about 100 variables and just around a 1000 rows, but like I said the problem is the width of the dataset not the depth.
2. Like I said, start by eliminating the interactions, then consider using other variable reduction techniques first to get your variable number down (factor analysis/principle components or clustering). The issue with those is will lose some explainability, but keep predictive power.
3. The [glmuttil documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmulti/glmulti.pdf) compares the package with alternatives, while highlighting their use cases, benefits and downfalls.

PS:  I ran my stuff on Win7, 64 bit, 16GB Ram, R version: 3.10 glmutil 1.07.
PPS: The author of the package was said to release version 2.0 last year that would fix some of these issues. Read more at the [source](http://vcalcagnoresearch.wordpress.com/package-glmulti/)