# What is the max number of variables once can use in an exhaustive all-subsets regression using glmulti()

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm

I am using the `glmulti()` package in R to try and run an all-subset regression on some data. I have 51 predictors, all with a maximum of 276 observations. I realize that the exhaustive and genetic algorithm approaches cannot compute with this many variables as I receive the following:

```
Warning message:
In glmulti(y = "Tons_N", data = MDatEB1_TonsN, level = 1, method = "h",  :
  !Too many predictors.
```

With these types of requirements (i.e. many variables with lots of observations), how many will I be able to use in a single run of the all-subsets regression? I am looking into variable elimination techniques but I would like to use as many variables as possible in this stage of the analysis. That is, I want to use the results of this analysis to make variable elimination decisions. Is there another package that can process more variables at a time?

Here is the code I am using. Unfortunately, because of the confidentiality associated with the project, I cannot attach datasets.

`TonsN_AllSubset <- glmulti(Tons_N ~ ., data = MDatEB1_TonsN, level = 1, method = "h",crit = "aic", confsetsize = 20, plotty = T, report = T,fitfunction = "glm")`

I am relatively new to this package and modeling in general. Any direction or advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Factor analysis may be a way to reduce the number of predictors. Chances are, many of the predictors in your set are quite correlated with one another (i.e., they contain similar information).

Comment: Along the same lines of ndoogan's comment, you could also try principal component analysis (PCA) to greatly reduce the dimensionality of your dataset.

Comment: I did run a PCA and was thinking of using variables with the largest loading values for each component (i.e. using the 15 variables with the largest loadings for component 1, component 2, and component 3).

Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 4):

glmulti is not restricted by the number of predictors, but by the number of candidate models.

By setting the argument method = "d", glmulti will compute the number of candidate models. Computing this takes considerably less time than running glmulti on method = "h" or method = "g".

If the number of predictors is too high, you will get the same error message. Thereby, you can try out the maximum number of predictors to be handled by glmulti within a reasonable computing time.

However, keep in mind that the maximum number of possible predictors depends strongly on whether you allow for interactions or not.

Furthermore, you can limit the number of candidate models by specifying the number of predictors in the model (eg. minsize = 0, maxsize = 1) or by excluding (exclude = c()) specific predictors or by excluding predictors in the model formula (y~a+b+c-a:b-1; this excludes the intercept and the interaction a:b). You find even more options for limiting the number of candidate models in the package documentation glmulti.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The glmnet package provides the facilities to do penalized modeling without the statistically flawed strategy of stepwise selection. (There seems to be a wide spread acceptance of the fallacious argument that using AIC protects one from problems of multiple comparisons.) It is incredibly easy to "find" statistically significant relations where there are none.

This is the result of using BabakP's suggestion with a random set of predictors:

```
pseudodata = data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=276,ncol=51))
pseudodata[,1] = rbinom(nrow(pseudodata),1,.3)

n1 = length(which(pseudodata[,1]==1))
n0 = length(which(pseudodata[,1]==0))
 for(i in 2:ncol(pseudodata)){
    pseudodata[,i] = ifelse(pseudodata[,1]==1, rnorm(n1), rnorm(n0))
    }
model = glm(pseudodata[,1]~., data=pseudodata[-1])
stepwise.model = step(model,direction="both",trace=FALSE)

> summary(stepwise.model)

Call:
glm(formula = pseudodata[, 1] ~ X4 + X6 + X10 + X17 + X21 + X23 + 
    X25 + X29 + X32 + X37 + X41 + X48 + X50 + X19, data = pseudodata[-1])

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.6992  -0.2943  -0.1154   0.3663   0.9833  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.25674    0.02561  10.025  < 2e-16 ***
X4          -0.03573    0.02394  -1.493 0.136727    
X6          -0.05045    0.02608  -1.934 0.054141 .  
X10          0.05873    0.02744   2.141 0.033235 *  
X17         -0.06325    0.02520  -2.510 0.012668 *  
X21          0.06420    0.02504   2.564 0.010906 *  
X23         -0.04961    0.02845  -1.744 0.082353 .  
X25          0.03863    0.02517   1.535 0.126035    
X29          0.04889    0.02381   2.054 0.041020 *  
X32         -0.03669    0.02509  -1.462 0.144841    
X37          0.09682    0.02507   3.862 0.000142 ***
X41         -0.05253    0.02676  -1.963 0.050704 .  
X48         -0.06660    0.02279  -2.922 0.003782 ** 
X50         -0.06955    0.02624  -2.651 0.008517 ** 
X19         -0.04090    0.02701  -1.514 0.131137    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.1674429)

    Null deviance: 55.072  on 275  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 43.703  on 261  degrees of freedom
AIC: 306.59

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure the lasso etc, protects against multiple comparisons. Only very recently have significance tests become available for the lasso (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7161)) and I am unaware of any software implementations. The natural approach (although sketchy from the point of view of significance testing) is to use OLS after the lasso (Candes and Tao's Gaussian lasso). This suffers from an identical problem to the one outlined. The paper linked also suggests in a footnote on page 3 that sample splitting may be used to provide reliable p-values for stepwise (ie AIC) selection.

Comment: @orizon: Thanks. Definitely interesting. I'm not sure this is the same problem that they address, since the problem posed wasn't really sparse in the sense of N << P.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience about 30 covariates can be used (with no interactions).

I recently answered a similar questions, check it out: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23878222/1778542

EDIT @Ben: Not enough points to comment =( says I need a score of 50 first. I'd commented this, if I could.

Comment: should this be a comment rather than an answer?